# get attribute of paperclip by string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a model User with an attachment avatar, and I need to find the avatar path only having the string "avatar"

```
user = Client.find 1
attribute = "avatar"
```

this way is getting me nil:

```
user[attribute].path
```

how can I correctly get the avatar path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
user.send(attribute).path
```